# Windows 8 app passing Binding variable from html file

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs

**Hi everybody** '
I am currently building a windows 8 app where I make a search and get result in the result page(result.html) as grid-ListView.

My problem is to get and pass item value to the Detail page
for example this is my html template:

```
<div id="basicsTemplate"
data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" >
    <div class="mediumListIconTextItem"
     data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ItemContainer" 
     data-win-options="{oninvoked: handler}>
   <div style="width: 160px; height: 60.34px;">
      <img src="#" data-win-bind="alt:business_name; src: photo_thumbnail"  />  </div>
   <div class="address" >
        <h3 data-win-bind="innerText: business_name"  style="width: 121px;"></h3>
        <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: category_name" style="width: 95px;"></h4>
        <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: business_no"  id="nober" style="width: 95px;"></h4>
        <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: town" style="width: 95px;"></h4>

    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

this is the handler function in my result.js

```
function handler(e) {

        var listFlyout = document.getElementById("nober");
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("text", listFlyout);
         WinJS.Navigation.navigate("../pages/businessPage/businessPage.html" );

        }
```

but it's returning me the **undefined** value in the businessPage.html

My real prolem is to pass this html attribute `data-win-bind="innerText: business_name"` to the detail.html page so that I can use it for forther rest-api

Please your quit help will be great to me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var x= lView.selection.getItems();
```

This will get the selected data array from the `getItems()` method in the WinJS library